Refresh a query loaded onto a worksheet
I made an invoice format in 'Sheet2' of my workbook. I attached a query to it. I change the value using a data validation list in cell 'E9'.
I press a button to call the refresh the query in the workbook so my invoice changes:
Sub RefreshAll()
    ' Replace "YourWorkbookName.xlsx" with the actual name of your workbook
    Workbooks("TEA.xlsm").RefreshAll
End Sub

I want for each value in the data validation to refresh the query, wait for it to finish fully, then export the sheet as a separate Excel sheet with the same name.
Public Sub Create_workbooks()

    Dim destinationFolder As String
    Dim dataValidationCell As Range, dataValidationListSource As Range, dvValueCell As Range
    
    destinationFolder = "C:\Users\Maqlly\Desktop\Vouchers"     'Same folder as workbook containing this macro
    'destinationFolder = "C:\path\to\folder\"  'Or specific folder
    
    If Right(destinationFolder, 1) <> "\" Then destinationFolder = destinationFolder & "\"
         
    'Cell containing data validation in-cell dropdown
    
    Set dataValidationCell = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("E9")
     
    'Source of data validation list
    
    Set dataValidationListSource = Evaluate(dataValidationCell.Validation.Formula1)
     
    'Create Separate Workbooks for each data validation value
    
    For Each dvValueCell In dataValidationListSource
        Call RefreshAll
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
        dataValidationCell.Value = dvValueCell.Value
        Worksheets("sheet2").Copy
         
       'there is now a new active workbook
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs Filename:=destinationFolder & dvValueCell.Value, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            .Close False
        End With
    Next
        
End Sub

It is exporting the sheet separately but fails to refresh the query to change the invoice.
I though it was an issue with the time required, but it seems not since I added the waiting protocol so that it finishes.

In the properties for the query is it set to Enable background refresh?  Make sure it isn't so it waits for the queries to refresh.

Setting the QueryTable.BackgroundQuery is set to false will fix the issue.

You could manually select each table go to Query tab -> Properties and uncheck `Enable background refresh".

Or we can do it using VBA.
Sub SetAllQueryTablesBackgroundQueryToFalse()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ListObject As ListObject
    
    ' Loop through each worksheet in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Loop through each query table in the worksheet
        For Each ListObject In ws.ListObjects
            If Not ListObject.QueryTable Is Nothing Then
                ListObject.QueryTable.BackgroundQuery = False
            End If
        Next
    Next ws
End Sub

